# "Method must have a return type" and "return must not be followed by an object expression"

Tags: c#, return, syntax-error

Im adding this method to a public static class

```
    public static LogMessage(Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        return ex; 
    }
```

When I do this, I get a message that says "method must have a return type"

and in the return I also get a message that says "Since 'Util.logMessage(System.Exception)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression"

How do I correct this?

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Your code doesn't match the error message...  It's typically a good idea to copy and paste the code and errors exactly as they exist from the IDE/compiler.

Answer (score 11):

You would need to change the declaration to return an Exception:

```
public static Exception LogMessage(Exception ex)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    return ex; 
}
```

Note that, depending on usage, it might make sense to allow this to be a generic method:

```
public static T LogMessage<T>(T ex) where T : Exception
{
    Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    return ex; 
}
```

This would allow you to use the resulting exception in a strongly typed manner.

Alternatively, you could just not return the exception, since Logging shouldn't need to return an exception in any case:

```
public static void LogMessage(Exception ex)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method signature has no return type. Based on the code, I'm guessing you want:

```
public static Exception LogMessage(Exception ex)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    return ex;
}
```

Which really makes no sense. There's no reason to return the exception after it's logged. You really could simply do:

```
public static void LogMessage(Exception ex)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Exception LogMessage(Exception ex)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    return ex; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the exception:

```
 public static Exception LogMessage(Exception ex)
```

If void:

```
 public static void LogMessage(Exception ex)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any method that has a return must have the return type specified.

Your situation:

```
public static Exception LogMessage(Exception ex)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    return ex; 
}
```

If you wanted to return a string:

```
public static string LogMessage(Exception ex)
{
     return ex.ToString();
}
```

The `void` modifier that is seen with methods that have no return is simply stating that the return is of type `void`. In this case your return would be the type of `Exception`. A method should always have a return type, whether it is `void`, a standard type such as `string` or `int`, or an object in the type that your class is, such as `MyClass`. It can also return a generic such as `List<T>` or `object`.

In this case though, as others have stated, it really does not make sense to return an exception.